# OpenGL glTranslate and glRotate

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glrotate

I need a function that applies a translation like `glTranslate()` to a point.
Does someone know of a function like `glTranslate()` and `glRotate()` to modify and retrieve a matrix to multiply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are thousands of [free matrix classe](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=matrix+class&meta=&rlz=#hl=en&expIds=17259,18167,23756,24878,26727,27400&xhr=t&q=free+matrix+class&cp=5&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=free+matrix+class&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=5640bd756f22a93a)s out there.  Have a hunt round google and then you can set up a translation and rotation without using the gl* functions at all ...

edit:  If you really just want to create the matrix without using a more than handy matrix class then you can define glRotatef( angle, x, y, z ) as follows:

```
const float cosA = cosf( angle );
const float sinA = sinf( angle );
float m[16] = { cosA + ((x * x) * (1 - cosA)), ((x * y) * (1 - cosA)) - (z * sinA), ((x * z) * (1 - cosA)) + (y * sinA), 0.0f,
                ((y * x) * (1 - cosA)) + (z * sinA), cosA + ((y * y) * (1 - cosA)), ((y * z) * (1 - cosA)) - (x * sinA), 0.0f,
                ((z * x) * (1 - cosA)) - (y * sinA), ((z * y) * (1 - cosA)) + (x * sinA), cosA + ((z * z) * (1 - cosA)), 0.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
               };
```

As taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle).

A translation matrix is really easy to create:  glTranslatef( x, y, z) is define as follows:

```
float m[16] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                   x,    y,    z, 1.0f
               };
```

You can look up matrix multiplication and matrix-vector multiplication pretty easily.

To make your life simple, though, you could just download a matrix class which does all this for you ...

Comment: thanks, but I don't need a class to manage the matrix, only a code like the 2 opengl functions wrote above

Comment: @ghiboz:  Updated my answer for you.  But I'd strongly recommend just using a matrix class.

Comment: @Goz, your matrix is missing the leading diagonal 1s. See my answer.

Comment: BTW- does your M[16] use the right convention (i.e. for multiplying a matrix by a column vector)? I believe it's a DX-ish matrix which you've shown and it should be a transpose of it if we follow the OpenGL conventions.

Comment: @Kos: Actually GL and DX use the same float order for their matrices (See 9.005 @ http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm).  That said the rotation may still be transposed.

Comment: This matrix is column-major (ie. "fortran" convention) if you want to multiply by a column vector (ie. "DX" convention), and row-major (ie "C" convention) if you want to multiply it by a row vector (ie. "GL" convention). Beware when multiplying.

Comment: @Gez - thanks for the link. Now I'm confused- I need to wrap my head around that :-). True that 'row-major' and 'column-major' are just internal representations and have nothing to do with, say, the x,y,z translation coords being in the last row or last column.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.dpfiles.com/dpfileswiki/index.php?title=Black_Art_of_3D_Game_Programming,_Chapter_10%3a_3D_Fundamentals#Transformations_in_3D) you can find general info about transformations using the matrices.

[Here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-7_04.html) you can find examples and complete functions that does matrix multiplications (either scaling, rotating or whatever). It is written in objective C, but it shouldn't be to hard to rewrite it in c++..